# Проблема с парсингом страницы c#

Tags: c#, .net, htmlagilitypack, веб-скрейпинг

Имеется код:

```
private string test ()
{
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.Cookies = new CookieDictionary();
    HttpResponse resp = req.Post("Здесь страница логина пароля");
    HttpResponse resp1 = req.Post("После логина пароля переходит на эту страницу, для вытаскивания данных");
    string k = resp1.ToString();
    var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(k);
    var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='process']/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span");
    return "Test" + node.InnerText;
}
```

После этого возвращается значение `NULL`. На каких-то сайтах все работает прекрасно. Путь до получения значения верный, беру через `XPath`, Где-то работает, где-то нет. Прошу помощи! После того, как ошибка вылетает, смотрю `string k`  в визуализаторе `HTML` и там показан весь текст, который мне и нужен. Но при парсинге все равно `NULL`.

Comment: Так а с чем помощь то нужна? Где не работает, конкретно там и надо рзабираться. Сейчас популярна асинхронная отдача содержимого страницы, т.е. то что вам надо может догружаться позднее и ваша реализация эту информацию не получает.

Comment: @Monk Как можно проверить это? Весь ли код загрузился в переменную или нет.

Comment: Как? 1. Дебаггером 2. Логированием на экран или в файл.

Comment: @nick_n_a я проверил, взял даже то значение, которое в самом начале документа появляется, и все равно его не парсит. String K у меня заполнено. node возвращает NULL

Comment: Ваш вопрос сводится к вопросу "как делать xpath запрос". Почитайте про xpath тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Не имея исходный текст, к которому вы делаете запрос (с точностью до байта) сделать выводы не возможно. Хочу заметить, что не все сайты придерживаются стандарта XML (имеют правильно-открытые закрытые теги и атрибуты) Поэтому такой подход будет работать не для всех сайтов.

Comment: @nick_n_a дело похоже в том, что на сайте перед стартом подружаются скрипты js. После идет вывод этой самой шапки, откуда нужно делать парсинг. Если я сохраняю HTML страницу на свой ПК и вывожу в загрузку HTML именно ее, то этот же Xpath запрос работает на ура! А как это сделать програмно, я не знаю

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так! Если так же будет значение Null, то измени значение в Pattern.

```
//Метод возвращает загруженную страницу HTML
public HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument GetHtmlDocument(string uri, string _method)
{
    //Класс для работы с загрузкой страницы для парсинга
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();

    //Выполняем запрос загрузки странницы с параметром запроса
    return web.Load(uri, _method);
}

string Pattern = "//*[@id='process']/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span";

//Получаем все узлы данного класса в HTML разметке
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection nodes = GetHtmlDocument("https://", "GET").DocumentNode.SelectNodes(Pattern);


//Перебираем все узлы в указанном месте
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    string value = node.InnerText;
}
```